# Rotating tick strings in pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqtgraph

Is there a way to rotate X-axis's tick-strings in `pyqtgraph`?

In `matplotlib`, it can be done using `setp(..., rotation=xxx)` (and other ways). E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(1000)
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=-45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics.html.